# How to make textbox readonly property false in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, readonly

I have one TextBox. I want to make textbox readonly property true or false during an event.

I set the TextBox readonly property as true by the following code:

```
   txtNoOff.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

But how to make textbox readonly property false? I have tried like below:

```
   txtNoOff.Attributes.Add("readonly", "false");
```

But it does not work. How to achieve this? I need all ur suggestions please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the `readonly` attribute: `txtNoOff.Attributes.Remove("readonly");`

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
txtNoOff.ReadOnly = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
txtNoOff.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
textBoxName.ReadOnly=true
```

or `False`